# Nextflow implementation using two input corresponding in two channels

Tags: nextflow

I am implementing a nextflow pipeline and I want to use two input, each input contains the file that i will use in the process

```
Process XXX {
    input : file from ch_fichier1 and ch_fichier 2 (i don't know which syntax i will use)
    output :  file("${sample}.vcf.gz"), file("${sample}.vcf.gz.tbi") into ch_Merged
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. You may like to see: [Understanding how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work)

Comment: I would recommend switching to the DSL2. It's much easier to understand.